# Where can we see professional discussions about vaccine development of the covid-19?

Tags: coronavirus, vaccination

Is there any place where people keep talking about the vaccine development professionally? I need the
latest news.

Comment: Private companies, not quite open science.

Comment: oh...how about relatively professional？Guys with strong biology background, but not work in vaccine companies.

Comment: Please see [Biology Meta for a question and answer](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses-how-to-ask-and-external-resources) giving various sources of information about coronavirus. However the links provided are to information not chat.

Answer (score 2):

The New York Times maintains a decent vaccine progress tracker: https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/science/coronavirus-vaccine-tracker.html

I also follow Derek Lowe's In The Pipeline blog: https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/
(It is not purely coronavirus-focused, but it has a lot of good information, and cites sources that you can go to for even more detail)